# How do I set conditional LaTeX code using R?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

Suppose in my `R`/`Sweave` created `LaTeX` document, I want to have `\subsection{Foo}` if in my `R` code we have that `x==1`, whereas if `x==2` in my `R` code I want `\subsection{Bar}` to be displayed.

How do I accomplish this? I know how to include `R` code by encapsulating it in `<<>>=` and `@` but I'm not sure how to do something such as the following (perhaps nonsensical) pseudo-code:

```
if(x==1)
    Show \subsection{Foo} in LaTeX document
else if(x==2)
    Show \subsection{Bar} in LaTeX document
```

What I also want to do that is very closely related is have subheading `\subsection{z}` in my LaTeX document, where `z` is defined strictly in my `R` code as some arbitrary string that I can toggle.

Comment: Does it work to use `cat("\subsection{Bar}")` for both pieces and then wrap the `<<>>=` and `@` around the whole thing.

Comment: @TylerRinker: Yes, if you use `results=tex`.

Answer (score 3):

\Sexpr{} can evaluate expressions inline:

```
Show \subsection{\Sexpr{if(x==1) "Foo" else "Bar"}} in LaTeX document

\subsection*{\Sexpr{z}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `results=tex` and `cat` the LaTeX code you want.

```
<<results=tex>>=
if(x==1) {
  z <- "Foo"
} else if(x==2) {
  z <- "Bar"
}
cat("\\subsection{", z, "}\n", sep="")
@
```